# Comparing all data in two tables whilst ignoring certain differences

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare

I am currently trying to compare two SQL server database tables. I've found various methods online, some which seem to work, other which don't.

The one I used which worked was:

`select * from table1
except
select * from table2`

The only issue with this then (as far as I am aware) is, the table says there is a difference between a 'NULL' value and a '0'. Which is correct, there is a difference.

However my question is, is there a way to do the comparison difference check, whilst ignoring certain conditions such as NULL and 0.

Comment: you mean something like this : `select isnull(column,'0'), othercolumns from table1 except select isnull(column,'0'), othercolumns from table2`

Comment: Won't that just replace all my nulls with 0 though, so in essence edit the data. Also is there a faster method as I have about 60 columns. If not it is a lot of typing (which I don't mind but if there is a faster method).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
select isnull(column1, 0) as column1 from table1 
except 
select isnull(column1, 0) as column1 from table2
```

to consider the values 0 and null as same.

Also, If you wish to consider more values as same like null = 0 = '' (empty string)

You can use case:

```
select case when (column1 is null or column1 = '') then 0 end as column1 from table1
except 
select case when (column1 is null or column1 = '') then 0 end as column1 from table2
```

Comment: Just to confirm, this isn't actually changing all my null's to 0's. It is just temporarily "thinking" them as the same value. Also as asked above is there a faster way of doing this for all columns as I have about 60 columns?

Comment: I just tried the top method and it didn't reveal any differences even though i specifically changed one of my tables to a value to create a difference. The value was '2308' so in one of my tables I changed it to '2307' The function above didn't output that there was a difference.

Comment: CREATE TABLE #Temp (co1 INT)
INSERT INTO #Temp values(2037)
INSERT INTO #Temp values(null)

CREATE TABLE #Temp1 (co1 INT)
INSERT INTO #Temp1 values(2038)
INSERT INTO #Temp1 values(0)

select isnull(co1, 0) as column1 from #Temp
except 
select isnull(co1, 0) as column1 from #Temp1
check what you got in this query.

Comment: That returned the value '2037'. My situation is I have table1 with 60 tables. Lets say coulmnA has a value of '2307' and I have table2 with same columns and columnA has a value of '2308'. I need a check which will cycle through check all columns. Should the values be 'null' or '0' then ignore the check, other differences should be reported back. So in that case it should report '2308' as a difference.